# Crear un RSS feed para varias categorias seleccionadas

Tags: rss

Si hago esto http://www.website.com/index.php?page=search&sCategory=123&sFeed=rss

puedo crear un RSS feed para una categoría en particular. Pero que hay si quiero crear un RSS feed para varias categorias seleccionadas? es posible? La versión de OSClass es 3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví así, por si a alguien le sirve

```
<?php


define('ABS_PATH', str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/'));
if(PHP_SAPI==='cli') {
    define('CLI', true);
}

require_once ABS_PATH . 'oc-load.php';

$mSearch = Search::newInstance();

$array_categorias = array("16","22","23","24","31","33","43","102","119","121","122","123","124");

$aItems  = $mSearch->doCustomSearch($array_categorias);

View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('items', $aItems);

 // FEED REQUESTED!
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');

$feed = new RSSFeed;
$feed->setTitle(__('Latest listings added') . ' - ' . osc_page_title());
$feed->setLink(osc_base_url());
$feed->setDescription(__('Latest listings added in') . ' ' . osc_page_title());

$contador_items = osc_count_items();

if(osc_count_items()>0) {
    while(osc_has_items()) {
        if(osc_count_item_resources() > 0){
            osc_has_item_resources();
            $feed->addItem(array(
                'title' => osc_item_title(),
                'link' => htmlentities( osc_item_url(),  ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8" ),
                'description' => osc_item_description(),
                'dt_pub_date' => osc_item_pub_date(),
                'image'     => array(  'url'    => htmlentities(osc_resource_thumbnail_url(),  ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"),
                                       'title'  => osc_item_title(),
                                       'link'   => htmlentities( osc_item_url() ,  ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8") )
            ));
        } else {
            $feed->addItem(array(
                'title' => osc_item_title(),
                'link' => htmlentities( osc_item_url() , ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"),
                'description' => osc_item_description(),
                'dt_pub_date' => osc_item_pub_date()
            ));
        }
    }
}

$feed->dumpXML();
?>
```